# Write headers to http get request

Tags: node.js, http

I have the following simple function:

```
export const makeGetRequest = function (token: string, options: any, cb: EVCallback) {

  const req = https.get(Object.assign({}, options, {
      protocol: 'https:',
      hostname: 'registry-1.docker.io',
      path: '/v2/ubuntu/manifests/latest'
    }),

    function (res) {

      res.once('error', cb);
      res.setEncoding('utf8');

      let data = '';
      res.on('data', function (d) {
        data += d;
      });

      res.once('end', function () {

        try {
          const r = JSON.parse(data) as any;
          return cb(null, r);
        }
        catch (err) {
          return cb(err);
        }

      });
    });

  req.write(`Authorization: Bearer ${token}`);
  req.end();

};
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
>       at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:580:17)
>       at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:575:10)
>       at Object.exports.makeGetRequest (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/docker.registry/dist/index.js:61:9)
>       at /home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/docker.registry/dist/index.js:67:13
>       at IncomingMessage. (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/docker.registry/dist/index.js:22:24)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1086:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:639:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

I also tried:

```
 req.setHeader('Authorization',`Bearer ${token}`);
```

I got a similar error relating to writing to the request after end.

Anyone know what's going on? How can I write headers to the request?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can simply pass as part of the HTTP.get request:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
    hostname: 'httpbin.org',
    path: '/get',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'authKey'
    }
}

https.get(options, (response) => {

    var result = ''
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        result += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log(result);
    });

});
```

BTW: HTTPBin is a useful testing site, you can do http://httpbin.org/get and it will send back the details of your call.

Comment: WHY doesn't the OFFICIAL documentation make ANY mention of this? https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass the headers as part of your options for the get function.

Right after the `path` you can add:

```
headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
```